# nginx reverse proxy that just forward HTTPS traffic

Tags: docker, nginx, reverse-proxy, docker-swarm

## From where we start

We have a web application `myapp` made of Docker containers. The 3 main containers are `database`, `backend` and `reverse_proxy`. The `reverse_proxy` runs `NGINX` with a conf like this:

```
server {
  listen              443 ssl;
  server_name         myapp;
  ssl_certificate     /run/secrets/myapp.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /run/secrets/myapp.key;
  ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
  
  set $backend http://backend:8000;

  # The backend HTTP api
  location /api/ {
    resolver 127.0.0.11;
    proxy_pass $backend;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_redirect off; 
    proxy_buffering off;
    proxy_request_buffering off;
  }

  # The frontend Single Page Application
  location / {       
    root /app/dist;  
    index index.html;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  } 
   
  location /static {
    alias /app/static;
  }
}
```

We run the containers with Docker Swarm (with volumes, secrets and default network), and everything is ok.

## What we want to achieve

We have a Debian VM somewhere on the web that we want to use as a demo platform for multiple versions of `myapp`, for example `1.0.0`, `1.1.0`, and `1.2.0`. We plan to run the 3 stacks with Docker Swarm, exposing a different ports for example `127.0.0.1:6000`, `127.0.0.1:6001` and `127.0.0.1:6002`.

Then we plan to run a reverse proxy for each of these stack, that would just forward the HTTPS traffic to the stack matching the URL, and serve an `index.html` file to point the available `myapp` version:

```
                Docker container                                  Docker Swarm              secrets
                   main NGINX
              +-------------------+                    +-------------------------------+    +-----+
              |                   |                    |      stack for myapp 1.0.0    |    |     |
              | URL=https://myapp.com/1.0.0/...   6000 | 443           HTTP            |<-->|     |
              |                   | <----------------> | reverse_proxy <-> back <-> db |    |     |
              |                   |        HTTPS       +-------------------------------+    |     |
              |                   |                                      |                  |     |
              |                   |                                   volumes               |     |
              |                   |                                                         |     |
              |                   |                                                         |     |
              |                   |                    +-------------------------------+    |     |
         443  |                   |                    |      stack for myapp 1.1.0    |    |     |
client <----->|  URL=https://myapp.com/1.1.0/...  6001 | 443           HTTP            |<-->|     |
        HTTPS |                   | <----------------> | reverse_proxy <-> back <-> db |    |     |
              |                   |        HTTPS       +-------------------------------+    |     |
              |                   |                                      |                  |     |
              |                   |                                   volumes               |     |
              |                   |                                                         |     |
              |                   |                                                         |     |
              |                   |                    +-------------------------------+    |     |
              |                   |                    |      stack for myapp 1.2.0    |    |     |
              |   URL=https://myapp.com/1.2.0/... 6002 | 443           HTTP            |<-->|     |
              |                   | <----------------> | reverse_proxy <-> back <-> db |    |     |
              +-------------------+        HTTP        +-------------------------------+    +-----+
                                                                             |
                                                                          volumes
```

## Questions

Is the good approach/design/architecture?

Is it ok to have the 3 secondary reverse proxies in the Docker stack manage the SSL (encrypt/decrypt, know the certificate and private key), and the main reverse proxy to just forward the HTTPS traffic? If so, what would its config look like, is it documented?

Comment: Just realized that the URL is encrypted by SSL so the main proxy has to decrypt it to route the traffic to the correct stack. So the encryption/description has to be managed by the main reverse proxy, and the secondary proxy will receive/reply HTTP traffic. Will make a small github repo if I find the time!

Comment: You might want to look at Traefik to replace nginx as the main proxy. It works off docker labels so it can react automatically to stacks being added and removed. nginx config is static and it will crash out unless special considerations are made if the config refers to dns names that don't resolve.

Comment: Regardless, as your main proxy is installed on the same docker node, there is no need to use unique ports for each deployment - just declare a common "nginx-ingress" network, and attach the main nginx and the stack nginx instances. they can now communicate directly by <stack>_<service>:6000 names.

Comment: I think the form of the question must change. "Is this a good approach..." is opinion based and results in a one word answer.